# Can't load wallet in CLI v0.13.0.2 or GUI v0.13.0.3 (error: std::bad_alloc | error: basic_string::_M_replace_aux)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli

Just downloaded the CLI binaries from getmonero. When trying to load a wallet in the CLI I get one of two errors:

```
Error: failed to load wallet: std::bad_alloc

Error: failed to load wallet: basic_string::_M_replace_aux
```

The errors don't appear together. Each time I try I get one of them, seems pretty random to me.

I can load the wallet using the old CLI binary.
Anything to do about it?

Edit:
The solution suggested by dEBRUYNE works in the sense that my wallet can now be opened. However, this way I lose information I cannot restore, about past outgoing transactions (specifically, addresses I sent to).
Furthermore, I just noticed that v0.11.1.0 doesn't support subaddresses yet, and I should note that my previous cli did support it, and my wallet did have subaddresses, so I guess this caused the incompatibility.

Comment: ZoneAlarm antivirus shows the Monero 13.0.4 zip file for Windows64 containing three viruses! not-a-virus.Net Tool.Win32.Tor.Jok.awo Sheesh. Will I EVER be able to install and use Monero without major problems?

Comment: @Guest - This is a false positive produced by your AntiVirus (as the monero software contains a solo miner). I'd advise to create an exception (i.e. whitelist) for the Monero software in your AV.

Comment: I did the steps for the GUI and got this response. Daemon failed to start Please check your wallet and daemon logs for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually.

Comment: @jerry - Did you recently update your GUI version?

Comment: I did recently update my GUI. As I was in the process of syncing the GUI my computer restarted and that's when I encountered this problem.

Comment: @jerry - do you still incur an issue?

Comment: Yes, I still have the issue. This was my original post:
https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/syncing-new-gui-and-laptop-restarted-midway-through-now-when-i-load-it-says-co I then went and renamed the wallet as per the instructions restarted the GUI and go this response. "Daemon failed to start Please check your wallet and daemon logs for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually."

Comment: @jerry - First, as an administrative note, please use the comments to respond, not create a new answer. Secondly, can you try these steps: 1. Close all Monero related software.. | 2. Browse to `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` | 3. Delete `data.mdb` | 4. Open the GUI. | 5. Instead of opening your wallet, click cancel / open another wallet, this will bring you back to the wizard. | 6. Select `Simple mode (bootstrap)` | 7. Reopen your wallet via the `Open a wallet from file` option. | Does your GUI function properly now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're running either CLI v0.13.0.4 or GUI v0.13.0.4.

Both errors imply an incompatible wallet cache, which results in `monero-wallet-cli` not being able to open it. Fortunately, the fix is quite trivial.

Perform these steps and you should be able to open your wallet again.

1. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located. By default, this is the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli`.
2. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`.

Note that, because you renamed the wallet cache, `<wallet-name>.keys` now doesn't have a accompanying wallet cache. Therefore, `monero-wallet-cli` will create a new wallet cache, which will simultaneously trigger a wallet refresh from scratch. A wallet refresh from scratch, however, shouldn't take that long to complete.

---

**GUI:**

If you're using the GUI, you can utilize the following steps:

1. Exit the GUI.
2. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).
3. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`
4. Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.

Comment: Currently there's no such method unfortunately. However, the information is retained in `<wallet-name>-old`.

Comment: Once subaddresses are supported in the official release, would my wallet be readable?

Comment: Did you create your wallet using compiled binaries (from master)?

Comment: I compiled them myself from master. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Then probably yes.